# C differential equation

Tags: c

I cant seem to figure out how to solve this problem.
The program uses a second to represent a year from during run time in an infinite loop. Inside the loop I need to solve this equation.

Differential equation: dP/dt = rP(1-P/K) – hP

where P(t) is the population that changes with time t (in years).

The symbols have the meanings:
dP/dt is the instantaneous population growth rate (as an increase per year)
r is the natural reproductive increase rate (as a fractional increase per year)
K is the population carrying capacity (maximum population the environment can support) 
h is the harvesting rate – rate at which the population is culled (as a fractional loss per year)

Depending on the run time seconds (each second represents 1 year) Correct example below

```
Simulation run time minute = 0; second = 3; millisec = 156
Year of simulation = 3
Rate of population change = 5180.209961
```

As you can see when my code is executed I cannot figure out how to calculate the correct population change. It depends on the seconds so it will vary.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
    {
    int option = 0;
    float initialPopulation = 0; //starting population
    float maximumPopulation = 0; //max population
    float harvestingRate = 0;
    float fractionGrowthPopulationRate = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int milliseconds = 0;
    char quit;
    int forever = 1;
    float total = 0.0;

    printf("Population Simulation\n");
    printf("1. run the simulation\n");
    printf("2. Quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    if (option == 1) {
        printf("ENTER SIMULATION PARAMETERS\n");
        printf("Initial population (typically 900000)?");
        scanf("%d", &initialPopulation);
        printf("Maximum population the environment can support (typically 1000000)? \n");
        scanf("%d", &maximumPopulation);
        printf("Initial harvesting rate (fraction per year - 0 for no\n harvesting)? ");
        scanf("%f", &harvestingRate);
        printf("Natural fractional growth population rate (typically 0.2 per year)?\n");
        scanf("%f", &fractionGrowthPopulationRate);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if (option == 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (forever != 'q') {
        printf("starting simulation\n");

        clock_t t;
        t = clock();
        //confused on how to code the formula
        total = fractionGrowthPopulationRate * initialPopulation* (1 - initialPopulation / maximumPopulation) - harvestingRate*initialPopulation;

        t = clock() - t;
        int seconds = ((int)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

        printf("Simulation run time minute = %d; second = %d; millisec = %d\n", minutes, seconds, milliseconds);

         printf("*****************************************************************\n");
        printf("Year of simulation = %d\n", seconds); //every seconds equals 1 year
        printf("Rate of population change = %f\n", total); //total should be calculated 
        printf("*****************************************************************\n");
        printf("Press w / e to increase / decrease harvesting rate.\n");
        printf("Current harvesting rate : %f\n", harvestingRate);
        printf("Press p / o to increase / decrease Max population supported.\n");
        printf("Current Max population : %d\n", maximumPopulation);
        printf("Press k / l to increase / decrease growth rate.\n");
        printf("Current growth rate : %f\n", fractionGrowthPopulationRate);
        printf("Press q to quit.\n");

        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &forever);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your code does nothing to actually solve the differential equation. For that you need an integrator, e.g. Runge-Kutta, that will numerically compute P(t). An example of a library that offers that kind of capability is [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-Integration.html). Coding a good integrator is not easy, although for simple problems you can get away with simple methods such as finite backward differences, trapezoid, etc. Another option is to solve your differential equation analytically and code the solution directly.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &maximumPopulation);` change this to `scanf("%f", &maximumPopulation);` Do the same with `harvestingRate`

Comment: For that differential equation, a closed form [solution is available](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%27(t)%3Dr*p(t)*(1+-+p(t)+%2F+k)+-+h*p(t)).

Comment: in general, never trust that input from a user.  For instance, what happens when the user enters 3 in the posted code?

Comment: Umm, why did you delete your entire question? As of now, it is entirely to broad and confusing to even understand what you are trying to say. You say `I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.` Well what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I've just rolled back your latest edit, which tweaked the title and removed all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. separates functionality into separate callable functions
3. contains the proper sequencing of events
4. hints that the simulation must take into account the prior iterations' results.
5. properly checks for user input errors
6. you will still need to complete the 'processParameters()` function
7. in `processParameters()`, be sure to include code for when the max population is reached

here is the proposed code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), scanf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>  // strerror()
#include <errno.h>   // errno

// prototypes
void inputParameters( void );
void processParameters( void );
void displayResults( void );
int  handleMenu( void );

// global data
float initialPopulation = 0.0f; //starting population
float maximumPopulation = 0.0f; //max population
float harvestingRate = 0.0f;
float fractionGrowthPopulationRate = 0.0f;
float total = 0.0f;

int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
int milliseconds = 0;


int main(void)
{
    int quit = 0;

    while( !quit )
    {
        int option = handleMenu();

        switch( option )
        {
            case 1:
                inputParameters();
                processParameters();
                displayResults();
                break;

            case 2:
                quit = 1;
                break;

            default:
                printf( "invalid option: %d try again\n", option );
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end while

    return 0;
} // end function: main


void inputParameters()
{
    printf("ENTER SIMULATION PARAMETERS\n");

    printf("Initial population (typically 900000)?");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f", &initialPopulation) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input of initial population failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Maximum population the environment can support (typically 1000000)? \n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f", &maximumPopulation) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input of maximum population failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Initial harvesting rate (fraction per year - 0 for no harvesting)? ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f", &harvestingRate) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input of omotoa; jarvestomg rate failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Natural fractional growth population rate (typically 0.2 per year)?\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f", &fractionGrowthPopulationRate) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input of initial population failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("\n");
} // end function: inputParameters


void displayResults()
{
    printf("Simulation run time minute = %d; second = %d; millisec = %d\n",
            minutes, seconds, milliseconds);

    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    printf("Year of simulation = %d\n", seconds); //every seconds equals 1 year
    printf("Rate of population change = %f\n", total); //total should be calculated
    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    printf("Press w / e to increase / decrease harvesting rate.\n");
    printf("Current harvesting rate : %f\n", harvestingRate);
    printf("Press p / o to increase / decrease Max population supported.\n");
    printf("Current Max population : %f\n", maximumPopulation);
    printf("Press k / l to increase / decrease growth rate.\n");
    printf("Current growth rate : %f\n", fractionGrowthPopulationRate);
    printf("Press q to quit.\n");
} // end function: displayResults


int handleMenu()
{
    int option = 0;

    printf("\nPopulation Simulation\n");
    printf("1. run the simulation\n");
    printf("2. Quit\n");

    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &option) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    return( option );
} // end function: handleMenu


void processParameters()
{
    int simulationDuration = 0;

    printf( "how long is simulation to run:");
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &simulationDuration ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input of simulation Duration failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("\nstarting simulation\n");

    total = initialPopulation;
    for( int i=0; i<simulationDuration; i++ )
    {
        //confused on how to code the formula
        total = fractionGrowthPopulationRate * total * (1 - total / maximumPopulation) - harvestingRate*initialPopulation;

        seconds = i; // in seconds
    }

    printf( "\nsimulation complete\n");
} // end function: processParameters
```